# Securing a Script Task in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I have a Script Task with C# code written inside. The code is supposed to make several REST calls to get some data. The credentials (username, password) are hard-coded within the script. What are the things to do to make sure that my package is secured, and what is the best practice in similar scenarios, keeping in my mind that there is no possibility to use third-party API connectors, and Script Task is my only option ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best approach would be to move Login and Password from script task into Package parameters and declare Password as being sensitive. Thus Login and Password can be specified later at Package start or stored at Environment variables. Sensitive Password parameter means that it will be stored encrypted and cannot be dumped to a file, for example.
The following code sample shows how to use encrypted password in your script task

```
Dts.Variables["$Package::YourPassword"].GetSensitiveValue().ToString()
```

If you need to distribute your package without disclosing Login and Password, switch to another authentication method, perhaps, with certificates. Script Task source code cannot be obfuscated, so everyone who can download the package from the server has an opportunity to inspect your Script Task.

Comment: I tried above solution: Dts.Variables["$Package::mypass"].GetSensitiveValue().ToString() in my script task, however, I still got this message "Accessing value of the parameter variable for the sensitive parameter "pass" is not allowed. Verify that the variable is used properly and that it protects the sensitive information" .. I am using this password to initiate a rest call using var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler()
                {
                    Credentials = new NetworkCredential(myuser, mypass),
                };

Comment: @khidir, do you use it inside Script Task or Script Component? The method `GetSensitiveValue()` is known to be not working inside Script Component, so the workaround is to read it in Script Task and store its value in some variable.

Comment: yes I am using a script task (C#) ,,  I read the sensitive parameter and stored it's value in a C# variable,, when I use this variable to authenticate an Http connection "var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler() { Credentials = new NetworkCredential(myuser, mypass), }" then I get the error above, "Accessing value of the parameter variable for the sensitive parameter "pass" is not allowed. Verify that the variable is used properly and that it protects the sensitive information"